# Cant find 'cancel_return' option on paypal sandbox page, using codeigniter and paypal lib

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use paypal lib https://github.com/jersonandyworks/Paypal-Library-by-RomyBlack on my Codeigniter project.

I am able to navigate to paypal n  pay for the product on sandbox, the problem is

1. There is no cancel_retun option on paypal.
2. There is no return url after the payment is completed

The below code is my controller code.

```
$this->load->library('paypal');

    $config['business']             = 'QD8HYTTSE4M38';
    $config['cpp_header_image']     = ''; //Image header url [750 pixels wide by 90 pixels high]
    $config['return']               = 'main/viewAds/info.php';
    //echo $config['return'];

    $config['cancel_return']        = $this->config->base_url() .'main/viewAds/22';
    $config['notify_url']   = $this->config->base_url() .'main/viewAds/30';

    $config['production']           = FALSE; //Its false by default and will use sandbox

    $config["invoice"]              = '843843'; //The invoice id

    $this->load->library('paypal',$config);

    #$this->paypal->add(<name>,<price>,<quantity>[Default 1],<code>[Optional]);

    $this->paypal->add('T-shirt',1,1); //First item


    $this->paypal->pay(); //Proccess the payment
```

The below is the library

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package    CodeIgniter
 * @author      Romaldy Minaya
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011, PROTOS.
 * @license     GLP
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @version     1.0
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Paypal Class
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Payment process
 * @author      Romaldy Minaya
 *

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Documentation
    This class let you make the payment procces based on paypal API,
    effortless and easy.

*1)Use the same documentation about the vars from [paypal page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/). 
*2)Customize the payment procces as you desire. 
*3)Build with love.

Implementation

*1)Copy this code in your controller's function

```
    $config['business']             = 'demo@demo.com';
    $config['cpp_header_image']     = ''; //Image header url [750 pixels wide by 90 pixels high]
    $config['return']               = 'sucess.php';
    $config['cancel_return']        = 'shopping.php';
    $config['notify_url']           = 'process_payment.php'; //IPN Post
    $config['production']           = TRUE; //Its false by default and will use sandbox
    $config['discount_rate_cart']   = 20; //This means 20% discount
    $config["invoice"]              = '843843'; //The invoice id

    $this->load->library('paypal',$config);

    #$this->paypal->add(<name>,<price>,<quantity>[Default 1],<code>[Optional]);

    $this->paypal->add('T-shirt',2.99,6); //First item
    $this->paypal->add('Pants',40);       //Second item
    $this->paypal->add('Blowse',10,10,'B-199-26'); //Third item with code

    $this->paypal->pay(); //Proccess the payment

The notify url is where paypal will POST the information of the payment so you
can save that POST directly into your DB and analize as you want.

With $config["invoice"] is how you identify a bill and you can compare,save or update
that value later on your DB.

For test porpuses i do recommend to save the entire POST into your DB and analize if
its working according to your needs before putting it in production mode. EX.

$received_post = print_r($this->input->post(),TRUE);
//Save that variable and analize.

Note: html reference page http://bit.ly/j4wRR
```

*/
class Paypal {

```
var $config         = Array();
var $production_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';
var $sandbox_url    = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';
var $item           = 1;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param   string
 * @return  void
 */
public function __construct($props = array())
{
    $this->__initialize($props);
    log_message('debug', "Paypal Class Initialized");
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * initialize Paypal preferences
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array
 * @return  bool
 */
function __initialize($props = array())
{
    #Account information
    $config["business"]     = 'QD8HYTTSE4M38'; //Account email or id
    $config["cmd"]          = '_cart'; //Do not modify

    $config["production"]   = FALSE;

    #Custom variable here we send the billing code-->
    $config["custom"]   = '';
    $config["invoice"]  = ''; //Code to identify the bill

    #API Configuration-->
    $config["upload"]        = '1'; //Do not modify
    $config["currency_code"] = 'USD'; //http://bit.ly/anciiH
    $config["disp_tot"] = 'Y';

    #Page Layout -->
    $config["cpp_header_image"]         = ''; //Image header url [750 pixels wide by 90 pixels high]
    $config["cpp_cart_border_color"]    = '000'; //The HTML hex code for your principal identifying color
    $config["no_note"]  = 1; //[0,1] 0 show, 1 hide

    #Payment Page Information -->
    $config["return"]           = ''; //The URL to which PayPal redirects buyersÃ¢â‚¬â„¢ browser after they complete their payments.
    $config["cancel_return"]    = ''; //Specify a URL on your website that displays a Ã¢â‚¬Å“Payment CanceledÃ¢â‚¬Â page.
    $config["notify_url"]       = '';  //The URL to which PayPal posts information about the payment (IPN)
    $config["rm"] = '2'; //Leave this to get payment information 
    $config["lc"] = 'EN'; //Languaje [EN,ES]

    #Shipping and Misc Information -->
    $config["shipping"]     = '';
    $config["shipping2"]    = '';
    $config["handling"]     = '';
    $config["tax"]          = '';
    $config["discount_amount_cart"] = ''; //Discount amount [9.99]
    $config["discount_rate_cart"]   = ''; //Discount percentage [15]

    #Customer Information -->
    $config["first_name"]       = '';
    $config["last_name"]        = '';
    $config["address1"]         = '';
    $config["address2"]         = '';
    $config["city"]             = '';
    $config["state"]            = '';
    $config["zip"]              = '';
    $config["email"]            = '';
    $config["night_phone_a"]    = '';
    $config["night_phone_b"]    = '';
    $config["night_phone_c"]    = '';

    /*
     * Convert array elements into class variables
     */
    if (count($props) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($props as $key => $val)
        {
            $config[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    $this->config = $config;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------- 

/**
 * Perform payment process
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array
 * @return  void
 */ 
function pay(){

    #Convert the array to url encode variables 
    $vars =  http_build_query($this->config);

    if($this->config['production'] == TRUE){
        header('LOCATION:'.$this->production_url.$vars);
    }else{
        header('LOCATION:'.$this->sandbox_url.$vars);
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------- 

/**
 * Add a product to the list
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array
 * @return  void
 */ 
function add($item_name = '',$item_amount = NULL,$item_qty = NULL,$item_number = NULL){
    $this->config['item_name_'.$this->item]     = $item_name;
    $this->config['amount_'.$this->item]        = $item_amount;
    $this->config['quantity_'.$this->item]      = $item_qty;
    $this->config['item_number_'.$this->item]   = $item_number;
    $this->item++;
}
```

}
// END Paypal Class

/* End of file Paypal.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/Paypal.php */

This is the transaction page i get
[image]

I am expecting it to return to my web site but it just stays there.

Kindly advice me on what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This library you're using is apparently using PayPal Standard, which does not guarantee the user will be returned to your site.

You can enable Auto-Return from within your PayPal account profile, but still, if the user closes the browser or goes somewhere else on their prior to the redirect happening they won't make it there.

If you want to ensure you always get back to PayPal you'll need to switch to the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec), which does guarantee that the user will end up back at your site.  I have a [PHP Class Library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) that will make this very simple for you.  That is my primary version that I continue to maintain, and it works with Composer so you can use that to autoload and make it available in CI.

Alternatively, I do have an old [CI specific version of the library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter) you might want to use instead.  It's not far behind right now, but I'm not going to maintain it like I am the primary one.

Either way, you'll be working with [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), and [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).

I would also recommend you take a look at [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/).  It will allow you to automate tasks in real-time based on transactions that hit your account regardless of whether or not the user makes it back to your site.